# Any way to statically initialize an Ada 2012 Map

Tags: dictionary, initialization, ada

I'm trying to create a global map that can be referenced by a procedure building a level.

It would be ideal if this global map could be populated statically in the specification (.ads).

Here's some broken code of me trying to guess how to do the static initialization part:

```
package Positive_to_Positive_Type is new Ada.Containers.Formal_Ordered_Maps
  (Key_Type => Positive,
   Element_Type => Positive);

Positive_to_Positive : Positive_to_Positive_Type.Map :=
  ((1 => 11),
   (2 => 12));
```

The errors are as follows:

```
expected private type "Ada.Containers.Formal_Ordered_Maps.Map" from instance at line 1
found a composite type
```

Now I get that I'm applying record-like syntax to trying to initialize a dynamic structure, is it even possible to initialize a map with values in an .ads or must it always be done with Inserts and the like in an adb?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the map a singleton, or do you want to initialize multiple instances of the map?

Comment: There is no way to specify the default initialization of a map, but each instance can be initialized through a function call.

Comment: It's a singleton. Ok, thanks for the clarification

Comment: You can also do initialization in the optional [*handled_sequence_of_statements*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-7-2.html) at the end of the package body.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but out of curiosity: do you really need a map? I was just dealing with something like this when I realized that I could just use an array. I was using an enumeration as the key, and suddenly I realized that the enumeration could be used as indices on an array. It turned out so much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at the package initialization level.
Assuming that you declared Positive_to_Positive and Positive_to_Positive_Type in a package specification 'A', your package body could look like:

```
package body A is
begin
   Positive_to_Positive.Insert (1, 11)
   Positive_to_Positive.Insert (2, 12)
end A;
```

Comment: Ok, this probably requires a "pragma Elaborate_Body" in the specification, correct?